# Notifications from access table

Tags: ms-access, notifications

I have an access database with tons of deadlines in it (Over a thousand) and would like to get a reminder a day before the deadline (through email, notification on the desktop, whatever). How do I do it?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205829/task-scheduler-will-not-run-macro

Answer (score 0):

In very broad terms:

- Construct a Query which obtains all tasks due the following day (and perhaps including overdue tasks) e.g. the criteria for the due date field might be `<= Date()+1`
- Create a Macro which checks whether this Query has any records (`DCount`) and if so, emails the Query to whomever you choose. The Macro would then quit Access.
- Open Task Scheduler in Windows and create a task to run the Macro in your database at a given time every day.